# kendo grid refresh doesnt work with crm dynamics

Tags: kendo-ui, dynamics-crm-2011, kendo-grid, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

When I add a row programmatically to a kendo grid and then call refresh the new row is not showing in the grid. This grid is in a crm dynamics webresource. 
Any ideas how I can get the grid to refresh properly? 
My code that is in the web resource:

```
  var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
  var datasource = grid.dataSource;
  dataSource.add({/* my object */});
  dataSource.sync();
  grid.refresh();
```

Comment: I think it is in Iframe. So, maybe you can do it with window.frames[yourFrame] then your code. But it is just suggestion.

Comment: Is that code in the form or in the web resource ?

Comment: Hi Alex the code listed above is in the web resource

Comment: remove sync & refresh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the casing of the datasource variable - a typo!

The working solution is:

```
var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
var datasource = grid.dataSource;
datasource.add({/* my object */});
datasource.sync();
grid.refresh();
```